# SFTP Server with user management sepatate from OS

Tags: linux, ftp

I want to setup an SFTP server on a linux machine.

I was thinking of using either [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) or [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/).

My main concern is that I want the administrator (which will not be me) to be able to manage ftp accounts (create/delete) without the need to go from the OS-specific user creation (`useradd`) etc, ideally via the ftp server interface.

Is there such a solution available for linux systems?

Comment: OpenSSH, AFAIK, does not provide FTP services.

Comment: Note that ProFTPD does not offer SFTP service (are you confused between SFTP and FTPS ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to "skin this cat" depending on the nuances of your requirement.

If you **only** need ftp accounts (is no ssh or login), proftp or pureftp will work fine - I do this for web hosting by running a database back end - once you add a user yo the dB they get ftp access - you can even knock up a web interface for it. You need to be aware of yserids and permissions and possibly chroot and homedirs- users will have an I'd associated with them which may or may not reflect back on the userid in the system (depending on dB config) so there are cross-user access/security concerns to consider.

If you want to be able to add system users without udin useradd or equivalent you should look into Pam, kerberos, SSSD (note 3 S's). These are all cross-platform mechanisms which can be leveraged to create user resources at a non-interactive/non-locsl level, but again the devil is in the details and what you are trying to achieve.

I do note that ftp is not designed for user management - I don't think its possible to do user management within DTP unless you get very creative with filesystem structures and use it outside its design parameters. BTW, the FTP protocol sucks, and needs to die. You may want to reconsider reliance on it. Look at SCP/SFTP - which uses an unrelated and way better protocol on top of SSH.

Comment: You are right about ftp, I updated my question to reflect my real need which is *s*ftp